# Rails Carrierwave upload multiple files undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-native, carrierwave

someone please can clarify why this

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

is happening on upload files with rails, carrierwave and react?

the rest of the code are very standard, so in the logs on upload image always the image attribute from post_attachments shows blank.

i suspected that the problem is with the rails loop over the post_attachments on post create, what do you guys think?

and i changed to

```
 params[:post_attachments].each do |image|
    img = PostAttachment.new
    img.image = image
    @post.post_attachments << img
  end
```

and still showing the error.

so please, someone has any idea why this with carrierwave and react?

here is post controller

```
  def create


    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)


    if @post.save
      #unless params[:post_attachments].nil?
        params[:post_attachments]['image'].each do |a|
          @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.create!(:image => a, :post_id => @post.id)

      #end


    end

    render json: "Posted successfully", status: 201
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

and the react

```
  async sendImage(forma) {
    let self = this;
    let errs = 0;
    let auth_token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN);

    try {
      let response = await fetch("https://localhost:3000/posts", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",

          //"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          Access: auth_token
        },
        body: forma
      });
      let res = await response.text();
      if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      } else {
        //Handle errors
        let error = res;
        throw error;
      }
    } catch (errors) {
      //errors are in JSON form so we must parse them first.
      let formErrors = JSON.parse(errors);
      //We will store all the errors in the array.
      let errorsArray = [];
      for (var key in formErrors) {
        //If array is bigger than one we need to split it.
        if (formErrors[key].length > 1) {
          formErrors[key].map(error => errorsArray.push(`${key} ${error}`));
        } else {
          errorsArray.push(`${key} ${formErrors[key]}`);
        }
      }
      this.setState({ errors: errorsArray });
      //this.setState({showProgress: false});
    }
  }

  async uploadImage() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    let image = params ? params.image : null;
    let photos = params ? params.photos : [];

    var self = this;
    let forma = new FormData();

    forma.append("post[title]", String(this.state.title));
    forma.append("post[body]", String(this.state.body));

    forma.append("post[post_attachments][image][]", 'teste');

    for (let i = 0; i < photos.length; ++i) {
      await fs
        .readFile(photos[i], "base64")
        .then(async blob => {
          //forma.append("post[post_attachments][image][]", 'teste');

        .catch(error => {
          console.log("loop err", error);
        });
    }

    self.sendImage(forma);
  }
```

log screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you debug or show your console log what does `params` contains?

Comment: @Gabbar thank you for your interest. yes, i'll place a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

params are like this: -

```
paramaters: {"post" = > .... "post_attachments" => {"image" => ["test"]}}
```

So image_params should be like this -

```
image_params = params[:post][:post_attachments][:image]
```

And

```
  unless image_params.blank?
    image_params.each do |image|
      img = PostAttachment.new
      img.image = image
      @post.post_attachments << img
    end 
  end
```

Comment: @lula However i've solved your issue `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass` but so far as i observed your params does not contain action dispatcher that is it's not image  datas. For that consider this to be accepted and create a separate question to asked how to send image attribute via react, as i have solved your original issue with this question. thanks.

Comment: thank you for your answer  @Gabbar, but somehow 

in the logs show undefined local variable or method `image_params'

Comment: ahh sorry, i forget to add the variable

Comment: @lula Have you defined `image_params = params[:post][:post_attachments][:image]` before use it? just place one line before each loop, please have a look at the answer.